# Getting memory usage of a process: comparing pmap to top

Tags: memory, pmap

I would like to get a process's memory usage and it seems that `pmap` can do that. However, the value it returns is different from what I see in `top` command.

```
# pmap 22080 | grep total
total          6588952K
# top | grep 22080
22080 ghatee    20   0 6588948 5.873g  11936 R 100.0  9.4   1120:17 pw.x
```

What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

'total' in `pmap` probably includes virtual/VSZ memory, which corresponds to the 5th column in `top`. If you look closely, both values differ only by 4K, something surely attributable to having executed the commands at slightly different times